# Cannot connect to mySQL in C++

Tags: c++, mysql

I'm trying to execute the code at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/1.1/en/connector-cpp-examples-complete-example-1.html

The code is compiling and running on  visual studio on my Win 11 PC.
I have installed the mySQL and it is running  (I can connect to it with DBeaver )

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

/*
  Include directly the different
  headers from cppconn/ and mysql_driver.h + mysql_util.h
  (and mysql_connection.h). This will reduce your build time!
*/

#include"jdbc/mysql_connection.h"


#include <jdbc/cppconn/driver.h>
#include <jdbc/cppconn/exception.h>
#include <jdbc/cppconn/resultset.h>
#include <jdbc/cppconn/statement.h>

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
cout << endl;
cout << "Running 'SELECT 'Hello World!' »   AS _message'..." << endl;

try {
  sql::Driver *driver;
  sql::Connection *con;
  sql::Statement *stmt;
  sql::ResultSet *res;

  /* Create a connection */
  driver = get_driver_instance();
  con = driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306", "user", "user");
  /* Connect to the MySQL test database */
  con->setSchema("dbschema");

  stmt = con->createStatement();
  res = stmt->executeQuery("SELECT 'Hello World!' AS _message");
  while (res->next()) {
    cout << "\t... MySQL replies: ";
    /* Access column data by alias or column name */
    cout << res->getString("_message") << endl;
    cout << "\t... MySQL says it again: ";
    /* Access column data by numeric offset, 1 is the first column */
    cout << res->getString(1) << endl;
  }
  delete res;
  delete stmt;
  delete con;

} catch (sql::SQLException &e) {
  cout << "# ERR: SQLException in " << __FILE__;
  cout << "(" << __FUNCTION__ << ") on line "     << __LINE__ << endl;
  cout << "# ERR: " << e.what();
  cout << " (MySQL error code: " << e.getErrorCode();
  cout << ", SQLState: " << e.getSQLState() << " )" << endl;
}

cout << endl;

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Hoever when I launch in debug it gets stuck forever and if I launch in run mode I get an erro during

con = driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306", "user", "user");

Ouput is:

```
Running 'SELECT 'Hello World!' ╗   AS _message'...
# ERR: SQLException in C:\Users\XXX\source\repos\DB operations\DB operations\DB operations.cpp(main) on line 55
# ERR: Unable to connect to localhost (MySQL error code: 3, SQLState:
```

I tried to replace 127.0.0.1 with localhost but the error persist.

What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks

I tried that the DB is active and user "user" with pwd "user" is working correctly.
I tried replacing "127.0.0.1" with "localhost.

I tried googleing the error

Comment: instead of `127.0.0.1` use `localhost`  also make sure that mysql is actually runnning

Comment: Make sure that your MySQL server is running to handle your connection request _properly_.